# Button in Cell and move View Controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I want move to View Controller after click button in cell. I try it with using click button:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
NSInteger rowOfCell = [indexPath row];
TwoParramCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"TwoParramCell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
        cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
        NSDictionary *dic = [self.arrayGoodInfo objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.delegate = self;
        if (rowOfCell == 0) {
            cell.btnSearch.hidden = NO;
        }
        cell.btnSearch.tag = indexPath.row;
        [cell.btnSearch addTarget:self action:@selector(searchBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.lblTitle.text = [dic objectForKey:@"stockModelName"];
        cell.isMeterial = @"NO";
        cell.txtContent.text = @"";
        cell.txtContent.tag = indexPath.row;
        if ([dic objectForKey:@"serial"]) {
            cell.txtContent.text = [dic objectForKey:@"serial"];
        }else{
            cell.txtContent.text = @"";
        }
        return cell;}
```

Here is searchBtnClicked:

```
- (void)searchBtnClicked: (UIButton *) sender{
    if (sender.tag == 0){
        SearchSerialVC *searchVC = [[SearchSerialVC alloc] initWithNibName:@"SearchSerialVC" bundle:nil];
        [self.navigationController pushViewController:searchVC animated:YES];
        [VTService showToastWithText:@"Search Serial"];
    }
}
```

Toast show but not push to Search Serial View Controller. What happen in here? Please, help me.

Comment: where is `searchBtnClicked` in? And can you check `searchVC ` ? is it `nil`?

Comment: searchBtnClicked `[cell.btnSearch addTarget:self action:@selector(searchBtnClicked:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];` is here. And search VC not nil, I check with other VC and same result.

Comment: Why is this tagged with Swift?

Comment: @toddg Sorry, It fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Step1. Comment out `[VTService showToastWithText:@"Search Serial"];`
- Step2. Check `self.navigationController`
- Step3. Check `SearchSerialVC`

`self.navigationController` may be is nil

Comment: Thanks you, self.navigationController is nil

Comment: @Rin Maybe you should edit your title.There is noting wrong with `TableView` or `Button in Cell` .